Swift Compiler Error: “Cannot call value of non-function type ‘module’” when Integrating PhoneNumberKit in Flutter iOS Project
Problem:
I’m encountering a Swift compiler error when trying to run a Flutter project on an iOS device (or simulator) the project depends on the PhoneNumberKit library in my Flutter iOS project.
Statement:
I am using phone_form_field to validate phone numbers in my Flutter  project. However, when I try to build the project with ios, I get the following Swift compiler errors: (Android works just fine)
•   Error: Module 'PhoneNumberKit' has no member named 'defaultRegionCode'
•   Error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'module<PhoneNumberKit>'
•   Error: Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'international'

Disclaimer: the project used to work fine , don't have a clue why it stopped compiling on ios.
The errors seem related to the project trying to use PhoneNumberKit in the Swift class. Here’s a simplified version of the Swift code I am using:

import Foundation
import PhoneNumberKit
import Checkout

class PhoneNumberValidator: Validator {

    var countryCode: String = PhoneNumberKit.defaultRegionCode()
    private let validator = PhoneValidator()
    private let phoneKit = PhoneNumberKit()
    private let validCharacterSet: CharacterSet = {
        var validInputs = "-+() "
        (0...9).forEach { validInputs.append("\($0)") }
        return CharacterSet(charactersIn: validInputs)
    }()

    init() {}

    func shouldAccept(text: String) -> Bool {
        CharacterSet(charactersIn: text).isSubset(of: validCharacterSet) &&
            text.count < Checkout.Constants.Phone.phoneMaxLength
    }

    func isValid(text: String) -> Bool {
        do {
            let formattedNumber = try phoneKit.parse(text,
                                                     withRegion: countryCode,
                                                     ignoreType: true)
            let phone = Phone(number: String(formattedNumber.numberString),
                              country: Country(iso3166Alpha2: formattedNumber.regionID ?? ""))
            return validator.validate(phone) == .success
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }

    func formatForDisplay(text: String) -> String {
        do {
            let formattedNumber = try phoneKit.parse(text,
                                                     withRegion: countryCode)
            return phoneKit.format(formattedNumber, toType: .international)
        } catch {
            return text
        }
    }

}

// MARK: Singleton behaviour
extension PhoneNumberValidator {

    static var shared: PhoneNumberValidator {
        if let instance {
            return instance
        }
        let newValidator = PhoneNumberValidator()
        instance = newValidator
        return newValidator
    }
    static private var instance: PhoneNumberValidator?

    /// Will deallocate the singleton source
    static func removeSingleton() {
        Self.instance = nil
    }

}


Here's an image of the errors inside Xcode


Here's my current depnendecies in pubpspec.yaml

name: app
description: "DESCRIPTION"

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 7.7.9+7036

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  app_tracking_transparency: ^2.0.6
  awesome_notifications: ^0.9.3+1
  badges: ^3.1.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  cached_network_image: ^3.4.0
  carousel_slider: ^5.0.0
  crypto: ^3.0.5
  device_info_plus: ^10.1.2
  dio: ^5.6.0
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.4
  firebase_analytics: ^11.2.1
  flutter_checkout_payment:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/lucasuracosta/flutter_checkout_payment.git
      ref: master # branch name
  firebase_core: ^3.3.0
  flutter_credit_card: ^4.0.1
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^6.0.4
  #TODO remmber to check tabby version before updating this pacakge to newer versions
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.8.0  #downgraded because of tabby package constraints ^1.5.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.2.2
  firebase_messaging: ^15.0.4
  flutter_phoenix: ^1.1.1
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.2.2
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.15.1
  pay: ^2.0.0
  get: ^4.6.6
  get_storage: ^2.1.1
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
  http: ^1.2.2
  path_provider: ^2.1.4
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2: ^5.3.0
  retry: ^3.1.2
  selection_menu: ^2.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.3.2
  shimmer: ^3.0.0
  sign_in_with_apple: ^6.1.1
  url_launcher: ^6.3.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.8.0
  icons_launcher: ^3.0.0-beta.3

  tabby_flutter_inapp_sdk: ^1.5.0
  phone_form_field: ^9.2.5
  sentry_flutter: ^8.7.0
  in_app_review: ^2.0.9
  is_first_run_plus: ^1.1.0
  jiffy: ^6.3.1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0
  sentry_dart_plugin: ^2.1.0 

I suspected the issue might have came from Phone form field package but i tried it on a new project and the project ran without any errors.
Tried Solutions:
1.  Updated All Dependencies: I ensured all dependencies, including PhoneNumberKit, Checkout, and others, are updated to their latest versions.
2.  Reinstalled Pods: Ran pod deintegrate, followed by pod install --repo-update to ensure all CocoaPods dependencies are installed correctly.
3.  Verified Project Configuration: Checked the Podfile, Build Settings, and other configurations to ensure they are set up correctly for the latest iOS and Xcode versions.

Additional Information:
•   Development Environment:
•   Xcode Version: 15.4
•   macOS Version: Sonoma 14.6.1
•   Flutter Version: 3.24.1
•   PhoneNumberKit Version: 4.0.0 (Havne't changed it at all)
•   What I’m Avoiding:
•   I prefer not to modify internal code or downgrade to older versions of dependencies unless absolutely necessary.

Question:
How can I resolve the Swift compiler errors when using PhoneNumberKit in my Flutter iOS project? Are there any known issues or workarounds for using PhoneNumberKit with the latest versions of iOS and Xcode? Any help would be appreciated!

I just found the solution posted three hours ago before posting my question
The solution was posted on this Question answered by user haroon-abutabar
For reference, here's the answer:

Remove Podfile.lock

in Podfile:

    target 'Runner' do
    use_frameworks!
    use_modular_headers!

    # Add This Line
    pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 3.7.6'

    flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    end

and then run:
   pod install --repo-update
   flutter clean
   flutter build ios

Would welcome any change to the answer to elaborate more on why this package caused the issue.

I am here just to add a little context of how it happened.
First, solution with pinning version in Podfile is right, in my opinion. Maybe it's worth to pin it to ~> 3.8.0 or something cause every version before 4.0.0 works.
Second, why version 4.0.0 breaks the build? The reason is this PR landed in 4.0.0. In this PR, PhoneNumberKit renamed to PhoneNumberUtility to avoid "shadowing" and corresponding warnings. Must say that is it right thing to do and it will happens sooner or later in any case.
Essentially, client-code should update usages of this framework and all will be good.
Third, problem here is that error is not in your code, but in iOS-side of flutter_checkout_payment package. It uses Frames framework, which is part of Checkout.com SDK. And this Frames framework depends on PhoneNumberKit and Frames is main consumer of PhoneNumberKit.
Problem in Frames configuration is here: dependency on PhoneNumberKit is not version-constrained. PhoneNumberKit updates and still satisfies Frame's dependency because there are no constraints. But API changed and code can not use new 4.0.0 version
Finally, I again think that pinning version in Podfile is OK. But, best way to fix it will be to reach out to Checkout.com somehow and ask to update Frames

I appreciate your input. As someone who isn’t a Swift developer, I would have never suspected this issue. As you mentioned, pinning the version in the Podfile seems to be a workable solution for now. However, I’m concerned that this might cause future issues, and I might have to resort to contacting Checkout.com to update the Frames dependency. Thanks again for your detailed explanation!
